# How to write a very basic SFTP client

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, ftp, sftp

My hosting company provides FTP, SFTP and shell access (no support for FTPS). I need to connect to it and upload our database. We want to switch from unsecured FTP to SFTP.

I've worked with an FTP library and we've been able to upload via FTP but I can't find an SFTP library and it looks like I might have to write one myself. I have the source for the FTP library. Is there any change I need to make to connect via SFTP?

My project is built in Flash and ActionScript3 and it may run in the browser so it may be possible to use a JavaScript library if available.

Comment: Can you use FTPS?

Comment: if you was done with that library, don't forget to share that Here. i guess to looking for a same library (SFTP) in JScript or Java or any thing and then compare it with your sources

Comment: I need SFTP. IIRC FTPS is supposed to be fazed out.

Comment: Source for my comment on FTPS http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/article.php/c14329/FTPS-vs-SFTP-What-to-Choose.htm Also my hosting company does not support FTPS so I cannot use it.